# Error: Error: Unknown version 3.2.1 for ruby on ubuntu-22.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have this problem occasionally in GitHub Actions workflows.

The full message is:

```
Run ruby/setup-ruby@v1.111.0
  
Error: Error: Unknown version 3.2.1 for ruby on ubuntu-22.04
        available versions for ruby on ubuntu-22.04: 3.1.0, 3.1.1, 3.1.2, 3.2.0-preview1, head, debug
        Make sure you use the latest version of the action with - uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
    at validateRubyEngineAndVersion (/home/runner/work/_actions/ruby/setup-ruby/v1.111.0/dist/index.js:65763:13)
    at setupRuby (/home/runner/work/_actions/ruby/setup-ruby/v1.111.0/dist/index.js:65664:19)
    at run (/home/runner/work/_actions/ruby/setup-ruby/v1.111.0/dist/index.js:65636:11)
    at /home/runner/work/_actions/ruby/setup-ruby/v1.111.0/dist/index.js:65797:40
    at /home/runner/work/_actions/ruby/setup-ruby/v1.111.0/dist/index.js:65799:3
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/work/_actions/ruby/setup-ruby/v1.111.0/dist/index.js:65802:12)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
```

What's the best way to solve this?

#### What I tried

I did a sensible thing and selected the closest available ruby version to the one I'm using (the app uses 3.2.1, so I selected the closest to that: `3.2.0-preview1`).

But now:

```
Run bundle install
Your Ruby version is 3.2.0, but your Gemfile specified 3.2.1
Error: Process completed with exit code 18.
```

Which is totally understandable, but problematic because the CI won't run, and I'm not sure how best to progress.

The most practical thing I can think of is downgrading the app to use ruby 3.2.0 to keep GitHub Actions happy. But I prefer to try to keep 3.2.1 and get the CI running in 3.2.1 if possible.

Comment: Or, you can simply use a container e.g. [ruby:3.2.1](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/ruby/3.2.1/images/sha256-f017c86a3035972269290f28190a8240f1186bb8aa2a976dbbaf604ae7c32b76?context=explore).

Comment: @Azeem great idea. I had some hacky ideas but that's way better.

Comment: I was initially attempting to add a condition based on `Rails.env` to the `Gemfile` but it doesn't execute ruby code (at least, I don't think it does).

Comment: Right. Are you already using `docker` or `docker-compose` for your ROR app?

Comment: @Azeem unfortunately not. I understand your suggestions conceptually, but I'm struggling to implement because that base you suggest has a few subtle differences to the one it's replacing, but I'm working through them iteratively. I think the database might be a challenge but I'll work it out. I feel like some good examples of rails workflows are a little lacking in google search results (at least full ones, for a complete application with a db and a few system libraries like libvips etc).

Comment: Right. You'll have to write a `Dockerfile` for your app itself, and then you can combine the DB with `docker-compose.yml`. Then you can use `docker-compose` in the GHA CI pipeline as well e.g. `docker-compose up`.

Comment: When you say you have the problem **OCCASIONALLY**, are you saying that sometimes the github action successfully installs ruby 3.2.1, and sometimes it gives an error message that the version isn't available??!

Comment: Ruby 3.2.1 was [released on 8th February](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2023/02/08/ruby-3-2-1-released/) (13 days ago), so there's a good chance you have a stale version of libraries somewhere, e.g. your `ubuntu-22.04` image hasn't been updated. But if you're saying that it's an **OCCASIONAL** problem, then I'm at a loss - I have no idea why it would inconsistently work/not work.

Comment: @TomLord sorry by occasionally I mean every few weeks or so on one app or another. As in, I either see it and disable the action or tinker with/replace the workflow until it works, never really understanding why, but rather arbitrarily looking on the web for an action that works and slotting my requirements into that. (Stabbing in the dark, really)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `setup-ruby@v1.111.0`, which was [released](https://github.com/ruby/setup-ruby/releases/tag/v1.111.0) on 28th June 2022. The [latest version of ruby that existed at that time](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/releases/) was `3.2.0-preview1`.

Ruby version 3.2.1 was [released on 8th Februrary 2023](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2023/02/08/ruby-3-2-1-released/).

Support for this new ruby version [was added to `setup-ruby@v1.137.0`, released on 9th February 2023](https://github.com/ruby/setup-ruby/releases/tag/v1.137.0)

The latest version, at the time of writing, is `setup-ruby@v1.138.0`, where ruby 3.2.1 support was also added for Windows.

---

tl;dr: Use a newer version of `setup-ruby` for ruby 3.2.1 support.

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked first time without requiring other required changes. Thanks also for all the links, meaning I'll know exactly what to do next time (go to the setup-ruby GitHub repo, click on 'Releases' and poke around until I find the relevant release). If I use docker in the future, I'll try @Azeem's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75519146/error-error-unknown-version-3-2-1-for-ruby-on-ubuntu-22-04#comment133240781_75519146) (it required a few other code changes in the workflow file, so would be a little more complex for my particular situation).

Comment: A future note for myself and for others; This line in the workflow: `uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1.137.0` is simply a reference to a GitHub repo, in this case https://github.com/ruby/setup-ruby (and release `v1.137.0`). I had previously thought it was some arbitrary thing that GitHub itself had set up, but it's not, it's a repo by the ruby community made to be referenced in a GitHub Action. I hadn't made that connection prior to asking this question.

Comment: Found myself back at this exact answer a few months on, so figured I'd add that an error message indicated it's usually best not to pin to a very specific version unless you have good reason to. So now I just use `setup-ruby@v1` (as opposed to a more specific version). More reading [here](https://github.com/ruby/setup-ruby?tab=readme-ov-file#versioning)